# During debugging, how to break execution after a specific line

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging a program and I have this line:

```
if (compareToName.equals(className)) {
      Set<String> properties = 
         reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.properties"));
}
```

I have a breakpoint in the line that starts with `Set<String>`...

I want to know the value of `properties` after the execution of  the line, but when I step over the line I'm over the block so the `properties` variable is not available in the variables window.

Comment: You can always mark the expression `reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.properties"))` and then right click and choose `Evaluate Expression...` from the context menu.

Comment: And you should also be able to set a breakpoint on the last curly brace `}`. That way you will be able to see the `properties` variable.

Comment: @maba:  I've seen it work on occasion, but I wouldn't rely on this behavior since it doesn't guarantee that the variable is always in scope of where the debugger is.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get the value immediately after you step over that assignment because the value doesn't exist outside of the `if` statement.  IntelliJ's debugger is still bound by the same rules of scope and variable lifetimes as other Java programs.

While I'm leery of this particular code snippet, getting the value isn't hard to do while in debug mode.

- Alt+Left Click while hovering over a particular snippet (in this case, you'd hover over the dot to the right of the `reflections` bit.
- Highlight the expression, then select "Evaluate Expression" (using the little calculator icon in the debug window).  By default it will prepopulate that field with anything that is highlighted so that you can execute an evaluation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt-F7 and enter the code you want to execute.
In your example:

```
    reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.properties"));
```

you will see the result.